# Visual studio code command doesn't work on WSL 2

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-code

For some reason, when I type the command `code .` from a WSL terminal I have the message:

```
Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal.
```

After some research, I tried to fix it with the following commands:

- `rm -r ~/.vscode-server`
- `code .`

It redownloads VS Code Server and it works correctly but just for one terminal instance. When I open a new terminal, I still have the message :

```
Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal.
```

I don't have the issue when I use the command `code` in a VS code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

open up a command line session, for example Powershell and type

```
wsl
```

then enter

```
code
```

It should clear it up.  If not, then adjust the path after entering the wsl layer and try running

```
code
```

again.